# How to write a code that takes a value as if from a dictionary without creating one?

Tags: python

I need to write a code that would remove specific words from a text. After some research I found out that it's best to replace all the words with " ", but replace() is not a good option as it removes characters from other words too. I found this re.sub() function and want to define a piece of code that would replace words from the given text (words are defined in a separate list). In most tutorials creating a dictionary for replacements was needed. I don't have one, so I wanted to define something that would check the list of stopwords and whenever found one in the text replace it with " ".

That is my code:

```
stopwords = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", "of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"]

import re
from functools import partial

sentences = []
labels = []
with open(path_bbc, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader: #this line of code divides my file into seperate lists (it's for an ML model)
        labels.append(row[0])
        sentence = row[1]
        for word in sentence:
            #this is where I don't know how to define what I want the code to do. The line below, of course, isn't working
            replacements = for word in stopword {word: " "}
            def helper(dic, match):
                word = match.group(0)
                return dic.get(word, word)
            
            word_re = re.compile(r'\b[a-zA-Z]+\b')
            sentence_rep = word_re.sub(partial(helper, replacements), sentence)
            sentences.append(sentence_rep) #here I want to append my temporary list where the operation of relacing words was happening to my final list sentences
```

This is the desired output

```
#Expected output
# 2225
# tv future hands viewers home theatre systems plasma high-definition tvs digital video recorders moving living room way people watch tv will radically different five years time. according expert panel gathered annual consumer electronics show las vegas discuss new technologies will impact one favourite pastimes. us leading trend programmes content will delivered viewers via home networks cable satellite telecoms companies broadband service providers front rooms portable devices. one talked-about technologies ces digital personal video recorders (dvr pvr). set-top boxes like us s tivo uk s sky+ system allow people record store play pause forward wind tv programmes want. essentially technology allows much personalised tv. also built-in high-definition tv sets big business japan us slower take off europe lack high-definition programming. not can people forward wind adverts can also forget abiding network channel schedules putting together a-la-carte entertainment. us networks cable satellite companies worried means terms advertising revenues well brand identity viewer loyalty channels. although us leads technology moment also concern raised europe particularly growing uptake services like sky+. happens today will see nine months years time uk adam hume bbc broadcast s futurologist told bbc news website. likes bbc no issues lost advertising revenue yet. pressing issue moment commercial uk broadcasters brand loyalty important everyone. will talking content brands rather network brands said tim hanlon brand communications firm starcom mediavest. reality broadband connections anybody can producer content. added: challenge now hard promote programme much choice. means said stacey jolna senior vice president tv guide tv group way people find content want watch simplified tv viewers. means networks us terms channels take leaf google s book search engine future instead scheduler help people find want watch. kind channel model might work younger ipod generation used taking control gadgets play them. might not suit everyone panel recognised. older generations comfortable familiar schedules channel brands know getting. perhaps not want much choice put hands mr hanlon suggested. end kids just diapers pushing buttons already - everything possible available said mr hanlon. ultimately consumer will tell market want. 50 000 new gadgets technologies showcased ces many enhancing tv-watching experience. high-definition tv sets everywhere many new models lcd (liquid crystal display) tvs launched dvr capability built instead external boxes. one example launched show humax s 26-inch lcd tv 80-hour tivo dvr dvd recorder. one us s biggest satellite tv companies directtv even launched branded dvr show 100-hours recording capability instant replay search function. set can pause rewind tv 90 hours. microsoft chief bill gates announced pre-show keynote speech partnership tivo called tivotogo means people can play recorded programmes windows pcs mobile devices. reflect increasing trend freeing multimedia people can watch want want.
```

The file has the following format:

```
['category', 'text']
[tech, tv future hands viewers home theatre systems plasma high-definition tvs digital video recorders moving living room way people watch tv will radically different five years time. according expert panel gathered annual consumer electronics show las vegas discuss new technologies will impact one favourite pastimes. us leading trend programmes content will delivered viewers via home networks cable satellite telecoms companies broadband service providers front rooms portable devices. one talked-about technologies ces digital personal video recorders (dvr pvr). set-top boxes like us s tivo uk s sky+ system allow people record store play pause forward wind tv programmes want. essentially technology allows much personalised tv. also built-in high-definition tv sets big business japan us slower]
```

Comment: Could you please provide the input file or a sample of the input and the exact output, form of output desired?

Comment: Instead of reinventing basic NLP logic, perhaps prefer to use existing libraries like `scikit` or NLTK.

Comment: @smartymcfly I edited the post to add that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```py
    # ... sentence = row[1]
    sentence = re.sub(
        r'\s?\b(?:%s)\b' % '|'.join(stopwords),
        '', row[1], flags=re.I)
```

You could `re.compile(...)` the regex before the loop and then use `compiledre.sub('', sentence)` inside the loop, but Python caches the regex for you anyway, so you'd be duplicating work which Python does behind the scenes for you anyway (and in some versions of Python doing it yourself is actually slower).

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression can perform all the word removals in one step using re.sub() with a pattern that contains all your stopwords separated by a pipe.

You will need to check for word boundaries around the pattern to ensure you don't replace parts of a word included in another: `\b(...)\b`.

```
import re

stopwords   = ["a", "about", "above", "after", "again", "against", "all", "am", "an", "and", "any", "are", "as", "at", "be", "because", "been", "before", "being", "below", "between", "both", "but", "by", "could", "did", "do", "does", "doing", "down", "during", "each", "few", "for", "from", "further", "had", "has", "have", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "he's", "her", "here", "here's", "hers", "herself", "him", "himself", "his", "how", "how's", "i", "i'd", "i'll", "i'm", "i've", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it", "it's", "its", "itself", "let's", "me", "more", "most", "my", "myself", "nor", "of", "on", "once", "only", "or", "other", "ought", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "over", "own", "same", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "so", "some", "such", "than", "that", "that's", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "there", "there's", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "this", "those", "through", "to", "too", "under", "until", "up", "very", "was", "we", "we'd", "we'll", "we're", "we've", "were", "what", "what's", "when", "when's", "where", "where's", "which", "while", "who", "who's", "whom", "why", "why's", "with", "would", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "you're", "you've", "your", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves"]
wordPattern = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(stopwords) + r")\b",flags=re.I)

def removeWords(S):
    result  = wordPattern.sub("",S,)          # remove words
    return re.sub(r" +"," ",result.strip())   # remove extra spaces


removeWords("am I bad and being a robot again")
'bad robot'
```

In your code, you replace the for loop with:

```
next(reader)
labels,sentenses = zip(*(L,removeWords(S)) for L,S,*_ in reader))
```